# Magento 2 - Remove filter in category page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I need to remove the category filter in Layered Navigation, but I can't find a way to remove the filter option in the layout arguments.

Anyone knows the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, I checked name of each filter in phtml and print only I needed.

I extends `Magento_LayeredNavigation` module and modified phtml files are:

- `Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml`
- `Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/filter.phtml`

Comment: That remove from the template, But in filter model that category included Bad performance.

Answer (score 3):

Go to admin > Products > Categories

Select category you do not want to display in filter

go to tab **Display Settings**

set **Is Anchor** to **NO**

[image: No]

Comment: If I set this option the other filters not work, but I need them (price and color yes, category no)